# Greying out a button until a certain value is chosen in a dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

If the default "Choose" is the selected item in this dropdown...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(Model.Data, "ID", "Info"), "Choose",new {@id = "DDL" }})
```

I want this button greyed out.

```
 <input name="Submitbtn" type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
```

I've tried this among others inside the condition but it doesn't change the button at all...

```
$('#DDL').change(function () 
{
       if ($("#DDL option:selected").text() == 'Choose')
        {
              ///which of these?
              $(".Submitbtn").attr('disabled', true);
              $("#Submitbtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
}
```

Comment: I *think* it is just `$(".Submitbtn").attr('disabled');`.

Comment: You are listening to changes on a `button` - those will never happen. You want to listen to changes on your select element instead. Remember you can only use each individual `id` value **once** *per-document.*

Comment: Ah so I need to listen to changes on the dropdown?  Do I give it an ID and refer to it that way?

Comment: As long you make sure the `id` you give it is unique, that would work.

Comment: Looks like your `select` already has an id `#ID`.   Also your submit button's id is `Submit` so it would be `$("#Submit").click(function()..` - if you manage to get to the `.attr("disabled"...` then it should be a simple case of trial and error to see which works - but it's the **selectors** that you've got wrong, not the `.attr`

Comment: I made the edit that I tried.  Still not working sadly.

Comment: Did you also change the `$("#ID option:selecte")` as you've now changed the `select` id that was found with `#ID`  (which you didn't need to change as it already had an id)

Comment: A bit confused here.  It's the DDL value that needs to be checked not on a button click. It's just the grey out property that needs to change on the button,

Comment: If someone could just write this out it would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverting back from the `@id=` to the original:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(Model.Data, "ID", "Info"), "Choose")
```

will create a

```
<select id="ID" name="ID">
```

so your jquery should be

```
$("#ID").change(function() { if $(this).text() == "Choose") {...
```

For the button itself, the `#SubmitBtn` must match the button id, which is `Submit` (without Btn), giving:

```
$("#Submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$('#ID').change(function() {
  if ($("#ID option:selected").text() == 'Choose') {
  
    $("#Submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  } else {
  
    $("#Submit").attr("disabled", null);
    
  }
});

// trigger/run on startup to disable as default is Choose
$('#ID').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ID">
  <option>Choose</option>
  <option value="val1">text 1</option>
  <option value="val2">text 2</option>
</select>
<input name="Submitbtn" type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: Quick thing.  When the Submit button is active and I click it to get to another View.  If I browser back to this page, the DDL still has the value that was selected but the Submit button is still grayed out presumably because it defaults to that?  Is there a way to refresh the cache?  If that's what it is?

Comment: You'll need to catch the browser back button and re-run `$('#ID').change();` (onpopstate off the top of my head - there's plenty of SO questions for it)